# Simple html dom weird behavior

Tags: php, html, css, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to parse a website which shows calendar events in a table and ran into some strange behavior.

### The html structure:

```
-----------------------------
date 1| - 1st event this date
      | - 2nd event this date
-----------------------------
date 2| - 1st event this date
      | - 2nd event this date
-----------------------------
date 3| - 1st event this date
-----------------------------
date 4| - 1st event this date
-----------------------------
```

As you can see, it's basically a `<table>` where each `<tr>` represents a date:

- The first `<td>` with the class attribute `class="ev_td_left"` contains the date string I want to parse.
- The second `<td>` with the class attribute `class="ev_td_right"` contains an unordered ist where each `<li class="ev_td_li">` represents an event entry.

### What I've tried:

I've tried parsing it with php using simple_html_dom.php:

```
foreach($html ->find('#jevents_body table.ev_table tbody tr') as $tr){

    $dateEl = $tr ->find("td.ev_td_left text", 0);
    $eventDate = parseDate($dateEl ->plaintext);

    // Iterate through all events this date
    foreach($tr ->find('li.ev_td_li') as $li) {

        // Get the event title
        $title = ($li ->find('a.ev_link_row', 0))  ->plaintext;
        print("Parsed: [$title, $eventDate]\r\n");
    }
}
```

### The Problem:

It seems like somehow it parses the whole page twice. My output look somewhat like:

```
Parsed: [1st event this date, date 1]
Parsed: [2nd event this date, date 1]
Parsed: [1st event this date, date 2]
Parsed: [2nd event this date, date 2]
Parsed: [1st event this date, date 3]
Parsed: [1st event this date, date 4]

//and here it runs again...
Parsed: [1st event this date, date 1]
Parsed: [2nd event this date, date 1]
Parsed: [1st event this date, date 2]
Parsed: [2nd event this date, date 2]
Parsed: [1st event this date, date 3]
Parsed: [1st event this date, date 4]
```

Does someone know where the problem is?

### Edit 1: The Markup:

As suggested, here's the html markup. (It's messy as hell):
http://www.akg-bensheim.de/termine/range.listevents/-

This produces this output:

```
Parsed: [Vorstand des Fördervereins, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Beginn der sportpraktischen Abiturprüfungen, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Christi Himmelfahrt, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Brückentag / beweglicher Ferientag, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Pfingstmontag, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Bundesjugendspiele, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Unterrichtsfrei wegen mündl. Abitur, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Mündliche Abiturprüfungen, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Fronleichnam, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Brückentag / beweglicher Ferientag, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Pensionäre: Sommerstammtisch, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Abiturienten-Gottesdienst, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Akademische Abitur-Feier, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Abi-Ball, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Sommerferien, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Vorstand des Fördervereins, 2015-04-29]
Parsed: [Beginn der sportpraktischen Abiturprüfungen, 2015-05-04]
Parsed: [Christi Himmelfahrt, 2015-05-14]
Parsed: [Brückentag / beweglicher Ferientag, 2015-05-15]
Parsed: [Pfingstmontag, 2015-05-25]
Parsed: [Bundesjugendspiele, 2015-05-28]
Parsed: [Unterrichtsfrei wegen mündl. Abitur, 2015-05-29]
Parsed: [Mündliche Abiturprüfungen, 2015-05-29]
Parsed: [Fronleichnam, 2015-06-04]
Parsed: [Brückentag / beweglicher Ferientag, 2015-06-05]
Parsed: [Pensionäre: Sommerstammtisch, 2015-06-09]
Parsed: [Abiturienten-Gottesdienst, 2015-06-24]
Parsed: [Akademische Abitur-Feier, 2015-06-25]
Parsed: [Abi-Ball, 2015-06-27]
Parsed: [Sommerferien, 2015-07-27]
```

As you can see, it somehow parses the whole thing twice!

Comment: how many tables do you have in that markup anyway? is it possible for you to post the html markup in question?

Comment: There are 2 tables in the div with id="jevents_body" but only one has the class attribute class="ev_table" The markup is so messed up that I didn't want to post it, but I will add it...

Comment: can't really tell whats going on with your code without actually really replicating the issue since you didn't post the html markup in question, so this is by a long shot, try `$html ->find('#jevents_body table.ev_table tbody tr', 0)`

Comment: you code works fine by the way, loaded the div with the table, i didn't include the another table above

Comment: It does not, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured out a work around for this, although I still don't have any idea why the parser was behaving so weird.

I basically ended up with checking every table row for its `plaintext` attribute and jump to the next loop if it has an empty text:

```
foreach($html ->find('#jevents_body table.ev_table tbody tr') as $tr) {
    $tmp = trim($tr ->plaintext);
    if(empty($tmp)) {
        continue;
    }

   //Parsing
   ...
}
```